# SQS triggers Lambda function over and over again, why?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My SQS is supposed to trigger a Lambda function once. It seems to trigger it repeatedly and I cannot find the cause.

Here's how the system works:

1. File is uploaded to S3 bucket (we'll call it `uploaded-docs`).
2. Uploading a file to `uploaded-docs/input/` triggers an event on the bucket, called `FileUploaded`.
3. Event `FileUploaded` triggers a Lambda function called `ProcessUploadedFile`.
4. `ProcessUploadeFile` calls Textract to analyze a document. The output of said Textract process is published (when finished) to an SNS Topic called `TextractComplete`.
5. `TextractComplete` has one subscription, the SQS called `TextractOutputQueue`.
6. `TextractOutputQueue` triggers a Lambda function called `GetOutput`. It's only supposed to run once for each file uploaded

I've noticed that when a file is uploaded, `GetOutput` is called over and over on the file and `Task timed out after 3 seconds` (Textract's `GetDocumentTextDetection` command called via `boto3`) can be found in the logs until it finally exceeds.

I also noticed that when a new file is uploaded, all the files in the bucket are called *again* in this process.

Some hypotheses:

1. The SQS queue items aren't being "consumed", such that they still exist in the queue after calling their respective Lambda functions, and because they still exist, they keep invoking the function.
2. The Lambda `GetOutput` is stuck in some sort of retry loop, and every time it times out, it calls the entire function again. This doesn't explain why the logs will be dead until I upload another document, and all the previously-uploaded documents enter the loop again somehow.

Comment: "Task timed out after 3 seconds" sounds like the reason. Since Lambda didn't successfully process the request, it gets added back to to the queue and retried.

Comment: If your process is taking longer than 3 seconds, you will need to increase the timeout period of the lambda function. You can do this in the console of the lambda function.

Comment: I would recommend to check code written in GetOutput lambda function. Try increasing GetOutput lambda timeout (default 3 seconds) and see if that function needs more time space to complete the functionality? When Lambda reads a message from the queue, it stays in the queue but becomes hidden until Lambda deletes it. If your function returns an error, or doesn't finish processing before the queue's visibility timeout, it becomes visible again. Then Lambda sends it to your Lambda function again. All messages in a failed batch return to the queue. Consult what is message retention period of SQS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all that commented, it was a very simple fix. Just increase the timeout of `GetOutput` to 10 seconds and the issue stopped.